# How to enable geolocation using Firefox/Chromium on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, geolocation

I'm building a node app that returns the user's geolocation, but I'm having a hard time testing it because I can't access geolocation on my computer. I tried using my localhost server in both Firefox and Chromium - Firefox asks for my permission but then can't retrieve it, and Chromium doesn't even get that far. When I deploy it to Heroku, I still can't access it on the computer. On my iPhone, Firefox still has no luck but Safari can do it. I don't know if my problem is in Ubuntu itself (can it block things like that?) or if both Firefox and Chromium have the same issue.

I doubt my code will be especially useful, but here it is anyway:

```
const locationButton = jQuery('#send-location');
locationButton.on('click', function() {
  if (!navigator.geolocation) return alert('Geolocation not supported by your browser.');

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
      socket.emit('newLocationMessage', {
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude
      }, function (mapLink) {
        alert(mapLink);
      });
  }, function () {
    alert('unable to fetch location.')
  });
});
```

The app is also up at http://rocky-brook-97128.herokuapp.com/.
Thanks for any guidance on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Chrome 50, the Geolocation API will only work on secure contexts such as HTTPS. If your site is hosted on an non-secure origin (such as HTTP) the requests to get the users location will no longer function.

Try it on https.
https://rocky-brook-97128.herokuapp.com/

[image: Chrome Permission]

[image: Chrome sending the geolocation]

Comment: I figured it out. I was emitting the wrong event, and nothing was displaying to the screen. lol I feel pretty foolish now - I didn't even dig into the dev tools. Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

(1) In a new tab, type or paste about:config in the address bar and press Enter/Return.

(2) In the search box above the list, type or paste geo and pause while the list is filtered

(3) If the `geo.wifi.uri` preference is bolded and "modified" or "user set", you can right-click > Reset it to the default

If Firefox sends anything to the geolocation service, the address should appear in the Browser Console
You can inspect and manage the permissions for all domains on the `about:permissions` page